# Как правильно хранить данные в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, reactjs, typescript, frontend, backend

помогите разобраться как хранить данные в БД правильно и какие вообще есть варианты помимо тех, которые перечислю. Предположим есть фронтенд, пусть для примера это будет некая страница статьи. Пока дело ограничивается полотном текста все вроде-бы окей, просто храним текст в БД, получаем на фронте - выводим в каком-то нашем компоненте на фронте. Но как быть, допустим, с какими-то выделениями текста средствами HTML? Допустим мы хотим иметь выделенный кусок текста жирным шрифтом, или, например, ссылки, в обычном html мы бы просто имели тег, но в реакте мы хотим иметь свой компонент ссылок или жирного текста для этого как это сохранить? Сохранить в БД HTML а потом, получив на фронте это все дело заменять на компоненты реакта или хранить JSX или как вообще это должно работать? Вот допустим, получаем мы с бека объект, в нем есть некий обобщающий блок ответа, а в нем разрастается дерево из составляющих статьи, допустим

```
 Response  
 posts 
   post1 
   post2 
   ...  
   post_n
```

В данном случае все супер легко, просто выводим посты.
Но если каждый отдельный пост имеет еще несколько чилдренов, у которых есть еще по паре чилдренов, то с этим уже довольно сложно взаимодействовать. Допустим есть несколько типов контента с разными полями, каждый из них мы храним в БД и пост как таковой просто родитель, оборачивающий их в единое целое. В этом случае мы можем получить каждый из них и обработать на фронте. Вроде все хорошо, но не создавать же отдельные сущности для жирненького слова в тексте или для ссылочки. Короче я запутался, помогите советом или источником в котором можно об этом узнать.

Comment: Если сильно упростить вопрос, как хранятся вопросы на этом сайте? Или как хранятся статьи на медиуме? Там тоже есть ссылки, изображения, блоки кода и прочие вещи, которые в каком-то виде, как мне кажется, хранятся в БД и каким-то образом обрабатываются на фронте.

Comment: Пока что самым лучшим вариантом кажется использование markdown для хранения контента. Так и HTML хранить не нужно, но при этом можно на фронте его распарсить как душе угодно. Но если у кого есть все-таки другие хорошие варианты то не молчите. Спасибо)

Comment: По вопросу баз данных было написано огромное количество литературы, потому что для каждой ситуации архитектура своя. Неужели вы думаете, что одним ответом на стаке можно раскрыть эту тему?

Comment: Да и к тому же здесь принято указывать конкретную проблему, с которой вы столкнулись, а ответ на этот вопрос может базироваться лишь на мнениях участников сообщества.

Comment: @T0xee.n17
Это я понимаю, вопрос в том, чтобы хотя-бы в общих чертах посоветовали направление. Одни говорят храни в строке html, другие говорят нет это плохо, и мне ламеру не понятно, как в итоге нужно. HTML вроде неплох, будет одно поле, но тогда придется либо заменять каждый тег на свои компоненты либо изначально хранить jsx либо как-то еще. Мне больше нравится вариант с чистыми данными. Тогда мы просто получаем json с кучей полей, каждое передаем в нужный компонент и все ок, но в этом случае в БД получаются огромные деревья.

Comment: @T0xee.n17
Поэтому я и спрашиваю, может кто посоветует где об этом узнать получше, либо кто имеет опыт скажет как делает или как делают другие, может есть какой-то стандартный подход. Какие вообще есть варианты. Я делал контент-модуль на беке, который состоит из нескольких разных сущностей. По идее чтобы каждый отдельный кусок можно было вкинуть соответствующему компоненту. И мне все-еще кажется что подход не плох, но минус чистого текста в том что в нем нет разметки, а HTML говорят хранить не безопасно. Придумывать велосипед в виде своей разметки и писать под нее парсер ИМХО вообще тупость.